# Contact Form 7 alignment issues on wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, contacts

I'm trying to use Contact Form 7 on WordPress, and for some reason the alignment is totally botched.

I thought it might be a bad version of the plugin, but it's version 5.7.6, and that apparently should be stable and fixed the 5.7 issues which cause this sort of problem.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[text title id:title class:title placeholder "Title"]

[text* Firstname id:FirstName class:FirstName placeholder "First Name*"]

[text* Surname id:Surname class:Surname placeholder "Surname*"]

[email* email akismet:author_email id:email class:email placeholder "Email*"]

[tel telephone id:telephone minlength:1 maxlength:20  placeholder "Telephone"]

[text company id:company class:company placeholder "Company"]

[textarea* Howcanwehelpyou id:Howcanwehelpyou class:How class:can class:we class:help class:you placeholder "How can we help you?*"]

[acceptance your-consent]  By ticking this box here you agree to our Terms & Privacy Policy[/acceptance]

[submit "Send"]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOJrn.jpg)

I have tried to put in column size classes but that didn't help. I also checked to see if there was an update issue but it should be fine.

Comment: _"Does anyone know how to fix this?"_ - no, because we can't tell what _causes_ it, from just a screenshot of the rendered results. We can't see what formatting your theme's stylesheet might be applying here that messes things up. We need a proper [mre] of issues like this.